# How to organize staging deployment of Java web app?

Tags: java, deployment, continuous-integration, build-automation

We have a Java web app, and a number of developers working with it. Every developer is working with his/her own feature, in its own branch. When the feature is ready - we want to review it and visually test (after all unit and integration tests are passed, of course). We want to automate this process of deployment. Ideally, we would like to let our developers click just one button somewhere to make the application deployed to `http://example.com/staging/branches/foo` (where `branches/foo` is developer's path in SVN repository).

Then, the deployment is reviewed (by project sponsors mostly), merged into `/trunk`, and removed from the staging server.

I think that I'm not the first one who needs to implement such a scenario. What are the tools and technologies that may help me?

Answer (score 1):

Typically, I would use a stage environment to test the "trunk" (ie all the individual branches for a release merged together). Several reasons for this:

- Stakeholders and sponsors usually don't have time to test individual branches. They want to test the entire release. It also tend to get very confusing for people not inside the immediate team to keep track of different, changing URLs and understanding why feature X works on one URL and not the other. Always keep it simple for your sponsors.
- It tends to become very messy and costly to maintain more than one instance of third-party dependencies (databases, service providers etc) for proper stage testing. Bear in mind that you want to maintain realistic test-data at all times.
- Until you merge all individual branches together for a release, there will be collisions and integration bugs that will be missed. Assume that automated integration tests won't be perfect.

All that being said, there are lots of good tools for automatic build/deploy out there. Not knowing anything about your build setup and deployment environment, a standard setup could consist of a build-server, maven and tomcat. The build-server would execute the build and deploy the resulting appplication to the test-server. If you are using maven and tomcat, there is a plugin available for this task (http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/introduction.html). There are a number of good build-servers out there as well with good support for maven. [Teamcity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) is popular, as is [Hudson CI](http://hudson-ci.org/).

Answer (score 1):

Basically you can use Hudson/Jenkins.

There are ways to manage have multiple deployments on one machine with some plugins, as stated on the following [post on Jenkins Users](http://jenkins.361315.n4.nabble.com/Automated-deployments-of-multiple-web-apps-with-Hudson-tp386125p386126.html), you'll just have to manage those multiple deployments to be the branches the developers are working on.

As @pap said, Hudson and other CI software build, test (if you have any tests in it) and deploy webapps, you'll just have to configure this procedure. Hope the link is helpful.